# check if a specific div exists by class and data attribute without looping all the elements with that class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs in my UI with the same class. Each of them has a different `data-id`.
I want to check if one of the divs has a specific value for the `data-id`.
I can do it with `.each()` but was wondering if there is a way not to iterate every time on all the divs.
If I find a div (by class and `data-id` value) I need to manipulate its content. If I don't find any div that satisfy the two criteria then I will perform some different activities.

What I have now (works but iterates every time the Dom)

```
let found = false;
$('.discussion').each(function(){
    if($(this).data("id")==myVariable){
        //I have found what I am looking for
        //do my stuff
        found = true;
    }
});
if(found===false){
    //I have not found what I was looking for
    //so I will add the div with that class and data-id
}
```

There can be even more then 10 divs with that class and this event will fire even 100 times a minute so performance may be impacted.

Markup is the following:

```
<div id="conversations">
    <div class="conversation" data-id="a"></div>
    <div class="conversation" data-id="b"></div>
    <div class="conversation" data-id="c"></div>
    <div class="conversation" data-id="d"></div>
    <div class="conversation" data-id="e"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: QuerySelector perhaps? ```document.querySelector(`.discussion[data-id="${myVariable}"]`)```. Guesswork without seeing the relevant HTML.

Comment: without markup this is probably only some guessing on the optimal solution here.

Comment: there is little need for markup but I will add.

Comment: Why not just select the specific div with the data-id you need? E.g. `$("div[data-id='whatever']").length`

Comment: because there is a second requirement I have to satisfy. If I don't find it I have other things to do. If I directly target the div as you say and it is not present how can I get it? @j08691

Comment: You'd wrap the above code in an if/then/else. If the length is 1 (true) do something, else, something else.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this.  Assumes ANY vs ONE here on length.
Probably more verbose than needed just to be clear on intent.

```js
const myVariable = 'b';
// leverage the length as a truthy/falsy boolean
let found = !!$('#conversations').find('.conversation[data-id="' + myVariable + '"').length;
console.log('found:', found);
if (found) {
  console.log(found, $('#conversations').find('.conversation[data-id="' + myVariable + '"').first().get(0));
}
if (!found) {
  //I have not found what I was looking for
  //so I will add the div with that class and data-id
  console.log('found:', found);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="conversations">
  <div class="conversation" data-id="a"></div>
  <div class="conversation" data-id="b"></div>
  <div class="conversation" data-id="c"></div>
  <div class="conversation" data-id="d"></div>
  <div class="conversation" data-id="e"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  doFunction($(this).attr('id'));
});

function doFunction(id) {
  if ($('.test[data-id="' + id + '"]').length) {
    console.log('Div found');
    $('#result').html('Data: ' + $('.test[data-id="' + id + '"]').html());
  } else {
    console.log('No div found with data-id equal to the ' + id);
    $('#result').html('No div found with data-id equal to the ' + id);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Sample Program</div>
<div id="result"></div>

<ul>
  <li id='test-1'>Click to test 1</li>
  <li id='test-2'>Click to test 2</li>
  <li id='test-3'>Click to test 3</li>
  <li id='test-5'>Click to test 5</li>
</ul>


<div class="test" data-id="test-1">Test 1</div>
<div class="test" data-id="test-2">Test 2</div>
<div class="test" data-id="test-3">Test 3</div>
<div class="test" data-id="test-4">Test 4</div>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)